# Duda sobre trigger para actualizar un campo de la misma tabla que lo dispara

Tags: oracle, trigger, update

He creado un `trigger` que dispara cuando modifico el valor de un registro de una tabla, en este caso la cantidad de componentes que tengo en la empresa. Es decir, el `trigger` sólo me permite modificar dicha cantidad si el nuevo valor es menor de 999. En caso de que no, salta una excepción. El caso es que cuando el valor que introduzco en el campo con un `update` es menor que 999, quiero que el propio `trigger` modifique también el valor de la columna importe (que es el producto de `cantidad*precio_venda`). El caso es que haga lo que haga `oracle` me devuelve el error de que la tabla está mutando y no sé como puedo hacer que el `trigger` actualice el campo cuando yo actualizo la cantidad. Para ser más claro copio debajo el código de la tabla que tengo creada y mi `trigger`, creo que lo que tengo que hacer es una transacción autónoma pero no soy capaz de realizar la correcta praxis, agradezco cualquier ayuda, gracias por adelantado :).

Tabla detalle que es la que dispara el trigger

```
CREATE TABLE DETALLE  (
 COM_NUM             NUMBER (4),
 DETALLE_NUM          NUMBER (4),
 PROD_NUM            NUMBER (6) CONSTRAINT DETALLE_NN_PRODUCTO NOT NULL,
 PRECIO_VENDA          NUMBER (8,2),
 CANTIDAD           NUMBER (8),
 IMPORTE              NUMBER (8,2),
 CONSTRAINT DETALLE_FK_COMANDA FOREIGN KEY (COM_NUM) REFERENCES COMANDA (COM_NUM),
 CONSTRAINT DETALLE_FK_PRODUCTO FOREIGN KEY (PROD_NUM) REFERENCES PRODUCTO (PROD_NUM),
 CONSTRAINT DETALLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (COM_NUM,DETALLE_NUM),
 CONSTRAINT DETALLE_CK_DETALLE_NUM_POSITIU CHECK (DETALLE_NUM > 0),
 CONSTRAINT DETALLE_CK_PVP_NO_NEGATIU CHECK (PRECIO_VENDA >= 0));
```

A continuación mi trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verifica_unidades
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF CANTIDAD ON DETALLE
for each row
BEGIN
IF :new.cantidad>999 then
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20511,'¡Cantidad demasiado alta!');
end if;
end;
```

/

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes *tocar* la misma tabla que está siendo actualizada/modificada dentro de la misma instrucción.

Para actualizar un dato dentro de la misma fila que estás procesando, lo que usualmente se hace es escribir un *trigger* `before insert` o `before update`. En este tienes acceso a los datos antes que se escriban en la fila y puedes manipularlos.

Algo como:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verifica_unidades
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CANTIDAD ON DETALLE
for each row
begin
  :new.Total = :new.cantidad * :new.precio;
end;
/
```

Recomendaría también hacer la validación como la que mencionas antes en el mismo trigger `before`, pues al elevar la excepción en el trigger after, el registro ya está *escrito* y esto obliga a la base de datos a deshacer esa escritura antes de devolver el control. En cambio en el before, la *carga* de trabajo del servidor resulta menor.

Para finalizar, vuelvo al tema de las ***tablas mutantes***. Es algo que no puedes olvidar trabajando con oracle y en ocasiones representa una limitante. Debes tener en cuenta, por ejemplo, que si durante un trigger en la tabla A, haces una operación en la tabla B, que a su vez dispara un trigger que trata de actualizar la tabla A, habrá un error, pues la tabla A estará *mutando* en ese momento.

Generalizando, desde que se lanza una sentencia `insert`, `update` o `delete`, la tabla sobre la que se lanza y todas las que sean modificadas como consecuencia de esta, estarán *mutando* hasta que se complete esa instrucción `insert`, `update` o `delete`. Es decir, hasta que la base de datos devuelva el control al cliente, script o *stored procedure* que lanzó la instrucción.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la información y por la ayuda, como bien me has dicho, he modificado tanto el trigger original como el que quería hacer y efectivamente, han funcionado a la primera los dos, te estoy muy agradecido, un saludo y termina bien el fin de semana :)